# ROS diamondback in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ros-diamondback, ubuntu, ubuntu-quantal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am new to ubuntu and have just installed ubuntu 12.10. Now I want to install ros diamondback and although I stick to the procedure given in ros wiki it keeps giving me an error. More precisely, when I type: sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full
it is appered a message that it could not find the package ros-diamondback-desktop-full.
What should I do??? It is important to get diamondback because I want to install the Hokuyo node later on.

Any ideas?????/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56929/ros-diamondback-in-ubuntu-12.10/) by [g10g18](https://answers.ros.org/users/4342/g10g18/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-03-04**:
The Hokuyo node works well on every version of ROS that I've used. If there's documentation that says otherwise, we should update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you can see here:
https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/blob/master/rep-0003.rst
Diamondback apt packages are only provided up to Ubuntu Natty (11.04).
ROS Groovy is currently the only version with apt packagesprovided for Ubuntu  Quantal 12.10

You can try installing diamondback from source if you really want that, however the hokyo node should probably also work with later ROS distributions.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1